# Get max of column using sum

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have one table with following data..

```
saleId amount date
-------------------------
  1     2000  10/10/2012
  2     3000  12/10/2012
  3     2000  11/12/2012
  2     3000  12/10/2012
  1     4000  11/10/2012
  4     6000  10/10/2012
```

From my table I want result with max of sum amount between dates 10/10/2012 and 12/10/2012 which for the data above will be:

```
saleId  amount 
---------------
1       6000
2       6000
4       6000
```

Here 6000 is the max of the sums (by saleId) so I want ids 1, 2 and 4.

Comment: What would "sum of max amount" be?

Comment: How `saleId` 3 is not in result?

Comment: i want only id with max sum of amount...here id 1 2 4 has 6000 amount so i want only such type of records...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use Sub-queries like this:

```
SELECT saleId , SUM(amount) AS Amount
FROM Table1
GROUP BY saleId
HAVING SUM(amount) = 
( 
  SELECT MAX(AMOUNT) FROM
  (
      SELECT SUM(amount) AS AMOUNT FROM Table1
      WHERE date BETWEEN '10/10/2012' AND '12/10/2012'
      GROUP BY saleId
  ) AS A
)
```

### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/eece2/22)

Answer (score 2):

This query goes through the table only once and is fairly optimised.

```
select top(1) with ties saleid, amount
from (
  select saleid, sum(amount) amount
  from tbl
  where date between '20121010' and '20121210'
  group by saleid
  ) x
order by amount desc;
```

You can produce the SUM with the WHERE clause as a derived table, then SELECT TOP(1) in the query using `WITH TIES` to show all the ones with the same (MAX) amount.

When presenting dates to SQL Server, try to always use the format YYYYMMDD for robustness.

Comment: The date range wasn't too important, but thanks for trying to help. It really depends on how you read the locale, I read it as d/m/y since I bow to the English queen, but that's why I made the statement about date formats.